# JavaScript access objects with wildcard for key

Tags: javascript, wildcard, leaflet

I have a JavaScript object like this:

```
e {_layers: Object, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 25, _map: e, constructor: function…}
  _initHooksCalled: true
  _layers: Object
    38: e
     _container: g
     _ini
     _mradius: 107
```

I want to access `radius`. The number `38` however changes from case to case. So I am look for some kind of wildcard.

```
myObject._layers[??]._mRadius
```

Comment: Will that be the only element in that object?

Comment: Yes. The value only changes from object to object.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
myObject._layers[Object.keys(myObject._layers)[0]]._mradius
```

Comment: This only gets me `Uncaught TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object `

Comment: Well, if your object is called "e"(?) then you just replace myObject with e.

Comment: My object is actually called `myObject`. Also `myObject[Object.keys(myObject)` works fine. But when I add the `_layers` part, then it doesn't work.